# java equivalent of # in python

Tags: java, python

I would like to convert this line of python :

```
z = 1.0 #1.0 = 85%, 1.6 = 95%
```

to java, like :

```
 double z = 1.0 ;
```

I don't know python and I'm just trying to transform [the reddit ranking algorithm for comments](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588) to java.

Comment: anything after # is comment, in java it would be //

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python `#` is comment.
In java you comment using `//` for single line comment and

```
/*
**
/*
```

for multiple line comments.

In java you can do it like this:

`double z = 1.0; //1.0 = 85%, 1.6 = 95%`

Comment: Thanks dude, I noticed right after posting seeing my code being commented, oddly my google researches didn't give any result. I'm gonna accept your answer in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Comments in Python start with the hash character, #, and extend to the end of the physical line. It is a single line comment.

`# this is the first comment
spam = 1  # and this is the second comment
          # ... and now a third!
text = "# This is not a comment because it's inside quotes."`

In Java its equivalent is //.

`//this is the first comment
int spam =1 // and this is the second comment
            //... and now a third!`

Also for multiple line comments in python, `"""..."""`,  is used. Its Java equivalent is : `/*...*/.`